# FileNotFoundException in runnable jar

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jar, nullpointerexception

I have an application that works perfectly in the eclipse launcher but not in the executable jar, I have copied the src into the jar and the .properties but I get this error:

```
Error in ConfigXML.java: problems with src/main/resources/config.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\victo\Desktop\IS1\config.xml (The system can not find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
        at configuration.ConfigXML.<init>(ConfigXML.java:84)
        at configuration.ConfigXML.<clinit>(ConfigXML.java:76)
        at gui.ApplicationLauncher.main(ApplicationLauncher.java:20)
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Locale.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Locale.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at gui.ApplicationLauncher.main(ApplicationLauncher.java:24)
```

These are that lines of the ApplicationLauncher.java:

```
public class ApplicationLauncher 
{ 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        ConfigXML c=ConfigXML.getInstance();
    
        System.out.println(c.getLocale());
        
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale(c.getLocale()));
        
        System.out.println("Locale: "+Locale.getDefault());
```

And the ConfigXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <businessLogic local="true"> 
    <businessLogicNode>0.0.0.0</businessLogicNode>
    <businessLogicPort>1099</businessLogicPort>
    <businessLogicName>Bets</businessLogicName>
  </businessLogic>
  <database local="true">
    <databaseNode>0.0.0.0</databaseNode>
    <dbFilename>src/main/resources/bets.temp</dbFilename>
    <dataBaseOpenMode>open</dataBaseOpenMode>
    <databasePort>6136</databasePort>
    <user>admin</user>
    <password>admin</password>
  </database>
  <locale>en</locale>
</config>
```

The config.xml is in the resources folder of the jar so I don't know what this happens, thanks.

Comment: What is ConfigXML?

Comment: ConfigXML is really badly written then. That will never work in a jar file.

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files, you can't use file APIs to access them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[image: Solution]

The solution is to paste the src folder next to the jar file, I have pasted it inside the jar file too using WinRar. It is because there is a line in the config xml that points to src/resources as the path of the needed resources

Comment: That is not a solution but a workaround! The contents of your resources folder will be in your jar file but in the "root" of it and on your classpath at least if you have build it with maven. Can your config file also do something like `<dbFilename>classpath:bets.temp</dbFilename>` ?

Comment: That is a really poor solution.

Comment: @Ivonet That config xml is like a trauma that I have sealed in the depths of my heart in order to remain my mental sanity.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I don't know what else you ask of a configuration file in xml to do.